# Vagrant Installer is not starting on Windows Server 2008

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead, laravel-5.1

I am trying to install Laravel's Homestead on an old Machine that I have. couple dependansies that Homestead will need in VM VirualBox and Vagrant.
I was able to install VM VirtualBox but everytime I try to install vagrant_1.7.4.msi it won't event show the installation process.

I don't get any error or any type of hints. I double click on the file and nothing happens. I tried rebooting my server which did not help.

I tried to run vagrant as admin and that did not help

any Idea why the installer will not start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
right click on the installer and select "Properties"

At the bottom of the "Properties" page under advanced button you will find a button called "Unblock" clock it and try to install the program.

This problem drove me crazy for 2 days I hope it help someone stuck!